# Redis3 cluster infinite waiting for the cluster to join

Tags: redis

I have 2 servers and 3 instances of redis3 in each of them. I have a `cluster-nodes` directory, where I have all the data of each instance. Here it is.

```
cluster-nodes/
|-- 7777
|   |-- db01
|   |  -- nodes-7777.conf
|   -- redis.conf
|-- 7778
|   |-- db02
|   |   -- nodes-7778.conf
|   -- redis.conf
-- 7779
    |-- db03
    |   -- nodes-7779.conf
    -- redis.conf
```

Here is my config file `redis.conf` under the `7777` directory

```
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-7777.pid
port 7777
dir /opt/redis/cluster-nodes/7777/db01/
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes-7777.conf
cluster-node-timeout 15000
```

When I try to start redis I get

```
./redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 127.0.0.1:7777 127.0.0.1:7778 127.0.0.1:7779 192.168.56.41:7777 192.168.56.41:7778 192.168.56.41:7779
>>> Creating cluster
Connecting to node 127.0.0.1:7777: OK
Connecting to node 127.0.0.1:7778: OK
Connecting to node 127.0.0.1:7779: OK
Connecting to node 192.168.56.41:7777: OK
Connecting to node 192.168.56.41:7778: OK
Connecting to node 192.168.56.41:7779: OK
>>> Performing hash slots allocation on 6 nodes...
Using 3 masters:
127.0.0.1:7777
192.168.56.41:7777
127.0.0.1:7778
Adding replica 192.168.56.41:7778 to 127.0.0.1:7777
Adding replica 127.0.0.1:7779 to 192.168.56.41:7777
Adding replica 192.168.56.41:7779 to 127.0.0.1:7778
M: 209d68fae9c64855d34972f660232eb96370a669 127.0.0.1:7777
   slots:0-5460 (5461 slots) master
M: 62e2b167a287b94b5154f7b9b0f226345baa81b7 127.0.0.1:7778
   slots:10923-16383 (5461 slots) master
S: 36ed59deceb01788db76abc0c2f22925a27295fc 127.0.0.1:7779
   replicates 2760b5fcc99c6563a7cf8deea159efb012309238
M: 2760b5fcc99c6563a7cf8deea159efb012309238 192.168.56.41:7777
   slots:5461-10922 (5462 slots) master
S: 16bf95ba9cb743c2a3caecaab5c2fd5121d80557 192.168.56.41:7778
   replicates 209d68fae9c64855d34972f660232eb96370a669
S: 30e7a5b4a94b5ff3a09f4809d6fd62edb2279b0e 192.168.56.41:7779
   replicates 62e2b167a287b94b5154f7b9b0f226345baa81b7
Can I set the above configuration? (type 'yes' to accept): yes
>>> Nodes configuration updated
>>> Assign a different config epoch to each node
>>> Sending CLUSTER MEET messages to join the cluster
Waiting for the cluster to join.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................^C./redis-trib.rb:534:in `sleep': Interrupt
    from ./redis-trib.rb:534:in `wait_cluster_join'
    from ./redis-trib.rb:1007:in `create_cluster_cmd'
    from ./redis-trib.rb:1373:in `<main>'
```

Here is the output from cluster nodes on the first server

```
62e2b167a287b94b5154f7b9b0f226345baa81b7 127.0.0.1:7778 master - 0 1435144555558 2 connected 10923-16383
36ed59deceb01788db76abc0c2f22925a27295fc 127.0.0.1:7779 master - 0 1435144554554 3 connected
209d68fae9c64855d34972f660232eb96370a669 127.0.0.1:7777 myself,master - 0 0 1 connected 0-5460
```

And this is from the second

```
16bf95ba9cb743c2a3caecaab5c2fd5121d80557 127.0.0.1:7778 master - 0 1435144648065 5 connected
30e7a5b4a94b5ff3a09f4809d6fd62edb2279b0e 127.0.0.1:7779 master - 0 1435144647057 6 connected
2760b5fcc99c6563a7cf8deea159efb012309238 127.0.0.1:7777 myself,master - 0 0 4 connected 5461-10922
```

It seems that all of them are started as masters? Is there something wrong in my configs?
Thank you.

p.s. when I try the same configs and start all instances in one server, everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in my case was that I was starting the service with localhost address,

```
./redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 127.0.0.1:7777 127.0.0.1:7778 127.0.0.1:7779 192.168.56.41:7777 192.168.56.41:7778 192.168.56.41:7779
```

In order to fix that `127.0.0.1` should be substituted with ip address of the local node, i.e.

```
./redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 192.168.56.40:7777 192.168.56.40:7778 192.168.56.40:7779 192.168.56.41:7777 192.168.56.41:7778 192.168.56.41:7779
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the 17777 17778...port，cluster need those port to communication。